# Append + symbol to ISD Code in Sqlite, Mysql

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database with country list, I have a column in country table named 'isd_code' now I want to append + symbol before each isd code through sql. Is there any query or shortcut to do this because I tried with excel which has already  `+` symbol appended but when I import this in sqlite it removes the  `+` symbol. Please help me.

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:mysql], [tag:sql-server] and [tag:sqlite3]?  Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I tagged those community who knows SQL. By the way I am using Sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the data with the symbol prepended:

```
SELECT '+' || isd_code FROM country
```

To permanently update the table:

```
UPDATE country SET isd_code = '+' || isd_code
```

Comment: But CONCAT function not working in SQlite